# How to create a smooks object from String (actual file content) in java?

Tags: java, freemarker, smooks

I had following code to create smooks object in Java:

```
smooks = new Smooks(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(smooksURI));
```

Where smooks URI is the path to the freemarker file in my project.

Now instead of getting the freemark marker file from Project, I have whole freemarker loaded in a String. I'm trying to create smooks object using the actual freemarker content in a string.

Something like

```
Smooks smooks = new Smooks(myFreemarkerContent);
```

Where myFreemarkerContent is the actual content of the Freemarker as a String.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize Smooks with a Freemarker template? That's not going to work anyway. Smooks needs to be configured with a Smooks config. The Smooks config is where you define the Freemarker (and other) stuff.